# Limits of $\tanh^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})$ and $\log\frac{a-x}{x+a}$ at $-\infty$

Tags: limits

From the definition of hyperbolic tangent, it can be shown $2\tanh^{-1}(x/a)=\log\frac{a-x}{x+a}$. Why the two show different limits at $x=-\infty$?

Comment: Wait how can you even take the limit as $x \to -\infty$ of that log function? For $\vert x \vert$ sufficiently large $(a - x)/(x + a)$ will be negative and so that log function won't even be defined.

Comment: The functions as written have domains $|x|<a$.